# Problem with php(mssql)

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I am getting the error

> "Warning: mysql_query(): supplied
>   resource is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in  on
>   line 21"

I have tried several different Queries none of which has worked. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
<html><body>
<form action="attempt1.php" method="post">
Interest Rate: <input type="text" name="interest_rate"><br>

<input type="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$server = <removed for safety>;
$login = <removed for safety>;
$pass = <removed for safety>;
$interest_rate=$_POST['interest_rate'];

$dblink = mssql_connect($server, $login, $pass) or die("Error1"); 
 mssql_select_db('<removed for safety>', $dblink) or die( "unable to select the database");
 $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO interest_rate VALUES('$interest_rate')";
 $res = @mssql_query($sqlquery, $dblink);


$query=" SELECT * FROM 'interest_rate' ";
$result=mysql_query($query,$dblink) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<b>Output to table</b><br>";
echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr><th>Interest Rate</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['interest_rate'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    echo $row['interest_rate'].""."<br>";
    }
echo "</table>";

?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: That code is *really* hard to read. Please set it as code...

Comment: What sort of database are you attempting to connect to? MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is not [mssql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php)

Comment: @middaparka: good job this is Sunday so I had a chance to get in first ;-)

Comment: The joy of being the early bird. (Enjoy your worms.) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing stuff here.

This call:

```
mssql_select_db
```

And:

```
mssql_connect
```

Are for **Microsoft SQL Server**.

And you are trying to use with a `mysql_query` call. Decide whether you are using **MySQL** or **SQLServer** and pick function calls accordingly.